# How to manually use org.springframework.validation.Validator validate() method?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-validator

I want to manually call validate(Object target, Errors errors) method from my validator which implements org.springframework.validation.Validator interface. When I bind that validator with @InitBinder in my controller class, Spring does it's magic and passes the Errors object itself. But I cannot figure from where should I get this Errors object myself when calling this validation manually. Creating new BeanPropertyBindingResult() for such method call does work, but then I do not get descriptive error response bodies as I would otherwise.

Is it even possible to get that BeanPropertyBindingResult object from somehwere in order to use my validation manually?

Or maybe there is a better way to validate PATCH requests? They are tricky since I have to fetch the object that I am updating first, only then it makes sense to run validations. And I would like to re-use same validations from POST request.

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

  private final MyValidator myValidator;
  private final MyService myService;

  @InitBinder("postRequest")
  public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.addValidators(myValidator);
  }

  // validation here in controller via @InitBinder works fine
  @PostRequest
  public void postWithBoundValidation(@RequestBody PostRequest request) {
    myService.doSomething(request);
  }

  // need to run same validations but in service
  @PatchRequest
  public void postWithManualValidation(@RequestBody PatchRequest request) {
    myService.doSomethingWithManualValidation(request);
  }
}
```

```
@Service
public class MyService {
  
  private final MyValidator myValidator;
  private final MyRepo myRepo;

  public void doSomething(PostRequest postRequest) {
    // do something
  }

  public void doSomethingWithManualValidation(PatchRequest patchRequest) {
    MyEntity entity = myRepo.findMyEntity();
    PostRequest postRequest = PostRequest.from(patchRequest, entity);
    
    // how to craft this Errors object correctly?
    Errors errors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(postRequest, "patchRequest");

    // only now I should validate
    myValidator.validate(postRequest, errors);

    // do something
  }
}
```

```
@Component
public class MyValidator implements org.springframework.validation.Validator {
  @Override
  public boolean supports(...) {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
    // do some validations
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little unclear, is `MyValidator` supposed to be `MyValidation` or vice versa?  I think all that you're missing is which `Validator` should be called and for why.

From looking at your logic, I think you want to inject `javax.validation.Validator` into your `MyService`.  Then you'll just call validator.validate(patchRequest);  It will return `Set<ConstraintViolation<PatchRequest>>`

Or, simply using the code as you have it, inspect the `errors` object after the call `myValidator.validate(postRequest, errors);`, like

```
if (errors.hasErrors()) {
  // do some funky stuff to handle the errors
}
```

Comment: but where can I get that errors parameter for `myValidator.validate(postRequest, errors)` from in MyService?

Comment: You already have it, though I would probably change it a little bit to read like this: `new BeanPropertyBindingResult(postRequest, postRequest.getClass().getName());`

Comment: thank you for your answer, I just realized that I was confusing Validator with Validation. Now I fixed the names in my example. I want to inject `MyValidator` which implements `org.springframework.validation.Validator` that has various validations. I don't want to have any validation specific logic in my service, just simply call myValidator.validate()